# Type annotation required even when provided

Tags: generics, rust, traits, type-inference

I want to do something like this:

```
trait Trait {
    type Type;

    fn function<T>(val1: &T, ty: T::Type)
        where T: Trait
    {}
}

struct Struct;
impl Trait for Struct {
    type Type = u32;
}

fn main() {
    let val = Struct;
    Trait::function(&val, 5u32);
}
```

And I got the error: `` error[E0284]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `<_ as Trait>::Type == _` ``
(c.f [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=60ca0bf085645278298c8be07e170f50))

But even when I add type annotation (`Trait::function::<Struct>(&val, 5u32)`), I have the same error.

Any clue about the reason of this error?

Comment: Do you actually mean for `function` to be generic? Seems like you want `T` to be `Self`.

Comment: @mcarton well, indeed, thank you! Still learning Rust and still have some troubles to do what I want. Let's say that I come from C++ and it's quite a different way of thinking :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trait doesn't mention `self` or `Self`, but it seems like you are expecting it to somehow infer which instance you intended.

Suppose you had another implementation of `Trait`:

```
struct Struct2;
impl Trait for Struct2 {
    type Type = u32;
}
```

Then, even though you are passing a `Struct` reference as the first argument, it would make sense for either implementation. This is ok:

```
let val = Struct;
<Struct as Trait>::function(&val, 5u32);
```

And this is ok:

```
let val = Struct;
<Struct2 as Trait>::function(&val, 5u32);
```

If you intended for the type passed to `function` to determine the instance, then the argument should be typed as `Self` instead of `T`:

```
trait Trait {
    type Type;

    fn function(&self, ty: Self::Type) {}
}
```

Now, it will correctly infer the instance without additional type annotations.

Comment: Thank you, like answered to mcarton, I'm still learning Rust and still have some troubles to do what I want. Let's say that I come from C++ and it's quite a different way of thinking